# Is there a human friendly encoding for filenames?

Tags: encoding, special-characters, filenames

I want to store files with arbitrary Unicode characters in their names, possibly including `/` and `\`. Is there any encoding that replaces such reserved characters but also stays human readable? By "human readable" I mean, that most characters stay unchanged. I thought about using percent-encoding, but it quickly gets unreadable with non-ASCII-characters.

For example, an encoding like this is what I'm looking for: `Foo/bär baz\qux 50%.txt` → `Foo%fbär baz%bqux 50%%.txt`

Comment: The underscore character?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying I should replace `/` with `_`? That would not be an encoding, because I could not tell if it was a `/` or a `_` before the encoding and thus I could not decode.

Comment: Yup. That’s exactly what I’m proposing. My take is any single file system that uses both / and \ is absurd and moronic.

Comment: I'm afraid we still have a misunderstanding. I explicitly asked for an encoding, because I want to be able to decode the filename again to get the exact same string I started with. Simply replacing a character with a different one won't cut it, since it introduces ambiguity.

Comment: ?  Okay, special for you. Use underscore for /, and dash for \, at least that will maintain “human readible” requirement.

Comment: "Human readable" depends on applications. On a commander/explorer the readability is completely different then within text and scripts, and much different if one should pronounce it (e.g. in a meeting/webinar/etc.). If you can, avoid a round-trip encoding/escaping (you do not want a file name wih just a different dash, or a different A (latin, greek, cyrillic, latin-in-asian-text, etc.